# How Could i enable Internet connection for Windows Store Apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, internet-connection

I created an App that needs a login  for getting user details and sending the challenge to choose the opponent by searching with their email id or giving Random search.

In Game Engine, its working properly. But, After completing the build from the Visual Studio I tried to put email id and giving submit will shows "please check the internet connection."(text that i used for getting if no internet connection in the system)

I enabled Internet(client & server) in the Appx.manifest.[image] Is that any other operation need to done for getting the acccess of those data...???

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: You may need to add an exception for your program to get through the firewall. I had to do this on my build server before it would connect out.